# how to separate business logic in RestAssured

Tags: java, json, rest, testing

We have REST webservice. It operates over JSON data representation. I would like to provide functional testing. I plan to use [RestAssured framework](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured). It provides understandable methods for testing correctness of output json.

Example, `get("/method").then().assertThat().body("obj.field", equalTo(5));`

But one problem arise: if json structure will change, all tests shall be invalid. For example, if `field` should be renamed to `field2` we shall fix all test with occurrences of `field`. The problem is very similar to web pages testing problem, where we should check presence of some web elements, etc. It was solved introducing by Page Object pattern. Does some similar solution exist for testing of REST api or could you advise some elegant one?

Answer (score 1):

In the example given in your question you validate the entire body of a response object in which case it is probable you will create brittle tests.

However it looks like REST-Assured already provides all the functionality you need to test specific parts of a JSON response:

[JSON example](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-1---json)

[JSON Advanced Examples](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-example)

[Using JSON Path](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#json-using-jsonpath)

You can even [map objects](https://github.com/jayway/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#object-mapping) and then do whatever you wish with the objects constructed, for example validation and manipulation.

See [here](http://www.hascode.com/2011/10/testing-restful-web-services-made-easy-using-the-rest-assured-framework/#Verify_JSON_GET_Request) for more examples.

Comment: If you feel your question is still not sufficiently answered, please edit and add more details.

Comment: Thank you for useful links. It seems that I should do the following: 1. create java classes, 2. deserialize json obtained from webservice to these classes, 3. write validation methods for these classes 4. use validation methods mentioned above in my tests. In case of json changes I should change names of fields of java classes and correspondingly fix methods of validation, but tests remain to be correct. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I think it depends on the depth (and length - timewise) of testing required. I have in the past done pretty much exactly what you described and wrote a framework to compare the actual objects produced with expected objects (or the relevant parts). There is a cost involved that is not trivial - 1. writing the framework 2. maintaining the framework and your objects (keeping them up to date with the responses). If this seems like overkill you could easily just test the relevant parts of the response without performing the mapping into objects first, using JSON Path etc.

Comment: Sorry that was in a previous project/role, and in C# anyway. I've used [AutoMapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) together with [Expected Objects](https://lostechies.com/derekgreer/2011/06/28/introducing-the-expected-objects-library/) libraries - perhaps you could find similar Java libs?

Answer (score 0):

Just like with an HTML page, one way to write tests less exposed to changes is to use a strategy to locate the target you want to evaluate.
With a web page you would use an XPath query, a CSS Seletor or directly the id to avoid dependecies over the ancestors.

So how to do it with a JSON ?
Well you could use a Regular expression, but it can get really messy or you could use an XPath like query for JSON :

http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/
  http://defiantjs.com/

So in your case, writing reliable tests is more about what you evaluate rather than the framework you use to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in REST API (especial public) are less frequent than in GUI. When changes in API are introduced they should be marked with new version and do not break old one (in most cases). So keep your tests as simple as possible, without introducing additional patterns, that will have some benefits - you can easily throw them away and write new. Hihger test framework complexity provides hihger maintanence costs. Any way in REST-Assured you may create `ResponseSpecification` and reuse it in assertions.